# Extremely slow website on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I'm trying to run a website locally, and it is very slow. Website uses DotNetNuke and IIS7.
When I create a new blank website - it runs fast. This particular one is slow.

What have I tried:

1. [disabling IPv6 support in browser](http://mkdot.net/blogs/lz/archive/2009/06/30/how-to-make-firefox-and-cassini-fall-in-love-again.aspx)
2. [Change maximum worker processes in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2375532/194076)
3. [I do not have AVG installed. And I disabled firewall and antivirus](http://www.40fingers.net/WeblogsNews/Weblogs/tabid/58/ID/38/language/en-US/DotNetNuke-very-slow-page-loading-issues-with-AVG-9.aspx)
4. [Remove Ipv6 support in Hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5938846/194076)
5. [Turn off batch in Web.config](https://serverfault.com/a/98679/98308)

None of these helped

Also, my website is even 5 times slower to respond when I need to recompile my solution.

update, if this is helpful, this is my basic trace:

```
Trace Information
Category    Message From First(s)   From Last(s)
aspx.page   Begin PreInit       
aspx.page   End PreInit         3.87710342363437E-05    0.000039
aspx.page   Begin Init          6.42382822151184E-05    0.000025
aspx.page   End Init            3.07985958803876        3.079795
aspx.page   Begin InitComplete  3.07989531820756        0.000036
aspx.page   End InitComplete    3.07990824188564        0.000013
aspx.page   Begin PreLoad       3.07991584404922        0.000008
aspx.page   End PreLoad         3.07993180859273        0.000016
aspx.page   Begin Load          3.0799394107563         0.000008
aspx.page   End Load            116.812769734266        113.732830
aspx.page   Begin LoadComplete  116.81281078595         0.000041
aspx.page   End LoadComplete    116.812820288654        0.000010
aspx.page   Begin PreRender         116.812828270926    0.000008
aspx.page   End PreRender           205.25318815735     88.440360
aspx.page   Begin PreRenderComplete 205.253225407951    0.000037
aspx.page   End PreRenderComplete   213.774178871307    8.520953
aspx.page   Begin SaveState         215.060896371107    1.286717
aspx.page   End SaveState           215.279060220539    0.218164
aspx.page   Begin SaveStateComplete 215.279100892114    0.000041
aspx.page   End SaveStateComplete   215.279114576008    0.000014
aspx.page   Begin Render            215.279130160444    0.000016
aspx.page   End Render              217.466907021738    2.187777
```

Comment: have you done any performance testing to see why it is slow in code?

Comment: No. the same website is fast in production.

Comment: do you have the debugger attached?

Comment: @Daniel A. White, I'm not sure how to check that, but I have debug=false in webconfig.

Comment: What language is this particular slow website programmed in?  Is there code in the App.Config that might be running for every request?

Comment: @Scottie, It is written in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it runs fast in production, but slow on your machine, it could be a connection to an external resource, ie database or other.

[Enable Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx) in your application and then see where processing is taking too long. You can help narrow this down by adding trace messages throughout your application in places you think could be causing the issue.

You could also see if this occurs on another workstation, with a clean OS, to determine if it could be something on your local machine causing issues.

Comment: Thanks, i've enabled tracing, where can I see results now?

Comment: browse to trace.axd in your website, or scroll down on your page if you set pageOutput to true.

Comment: Okay. updated post with my first table of trace info. Does it mean that I have to look at pageload or page_prerender events? They are almost empty.

Comment: You do need to look in both of these places, as they are certainly causing your performance issues. The first place I would look is connections to any outside resources, web services, databases, external files, etc. Add Trace.warn messages at the beginning and end of each of the places to give you specific timings on them.

Answer (score 1):

You could grab the [ANTS Performance Profiler from Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) and see if it points you in the right direction. There is a 14 day free trial, I've used this tool in the past to find bottlenecks and other issues and it is worth every penny.